# Is there a simpler solution than to pivot longer and pivot wider?

Tags: r

Let's say that the `data` looks like this.

```
    region  year  people  cash
0   area1   2020  32      29
1   area1   2021  43      40
2   area2   2020  51      23
3   area2   2021  99      98
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
    variable  area1  area2  year
0   people    32     51     2020
1   cash      29     23     2020
2   people    43     99     2021
3   cash      40     98     2021
```

It took a while to figure out how to transform the data. I've finally come up with the following code:

```
data_long <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(region,year)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = region) %>%
  select(variable, area1, area2, year)
```

However, it seems quite unnatural to `pivot_longer` and then immediately `pivot_wider`. I feel like I'm missing a much simpler solution here somewhere.

Comment: is this question a pandas question or R? the code you shared is certainly not pandas

Comment: Sorry, you're right - it's about R.

Comment: Don't let it feel unnatural. The tidy data philosophy would say that the long form is the "standard" or "tidy" state of the data. You can usually go from a wide "messy" state to the tidy state, and from the tidy state to any messy state, but going from one messy state to another can be difficult.

Comment: So as long as it's working...? Doing `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` one after the other is not a big "faux pa"? Would there be any other way to achieve something similar? I'm still learning the aspects of data wrangling and I am just not entirely sure that my solution is optimal.